# Normalization with error in denominator

Tags: normalization

I am trying to come up with a proper way to normalize my data. Using a microscope I want to count the percentage of green cells in a population. However, only ~0.1% of all cells are green. I decided I want to count 30 green cells, this would mean that I need to count roughly 30,000 cells to find 30 green ones. However, I do not want to manually count 30,000 cells. So I came up with a short cut. I know the exact area of a single frame under the microscope. So if I know how many cells are in a single frame, and I keep track of how many frames I imaged, I do not need to count individual non-green cells. To estimate the number of cells/frame I counted 10 random frames, this allows me to estimate an average (+/- stdev) number of cells per frame and this gives me the denominator I need.
However, I am stuck at the next step. So I count green cells and have an extrapolated total number of cells. When reporting the % of green cells, I would normally # green cells/total cells. But now, I need to keep the error of the estimate into account.
I am not sure how I would do that. Furthermore, I am treating these cells with different drugs to see whether the number of green cells changes. What statistics should I use, or does the variation of the denominator not matter?
thanks!!

Comment: Is it 0.01% or 0.10%? 30 out of 30,000 is 0.10%.

Comment: You are correct. Edited

Answer (score 1):

You can create a confidence interval on the mean number of cells/frame using the standard $t$ interval. Let's say you find a mean of 5000 cells/frame and a 95% confidence interval of [4890, 5110].

Now when you estimate your green percentage, your count of green cells and your total frames counted are both known. Suppose you find 27 green cells by counting 5 frames.

Your estimate of the green cell percentage is then $$G = {{27} \over {5(5000)}}=0.00108 = 0.1080\%$$

For a lower bound, use 5110 in the denominator instead of 5000 to get 0.1057% 
Similarly, get the upper bound by using 4890 in the denominator to get 0.1104%

If the estimate is not precise enough, collect more data on your cells/frame counts to make your confidence interval on the mean number of cells/frame narrower. This in turn will narrow your confidence interval on the green cell percentage.

Comment: is there a reason why 95% CI is a better choice over standard deviation?

Comment: My guess is the convention varies by discipline. If you want to report the estimate plus or minus one standard deviation and that is what your colleagues use and accept, go ahead. I would not use such an interval because it's coverage is far less than what I find to be appropriate. It would only contain the true value about 68% of the time.